# how to identify highest value key in nested dictionary?

Tags: python

As a python newbie, I have a dictionary d:

```
d={'a':{'1':4,'2':6},'b':{'1':5,'2':10}}
```

I need to find for each key ('a','b') the sub-key for the highest value and bundle them together in a new dictionary, newd, which looks like

```
newd={'a':'2', 'b':'2'}
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What should this do if two keys have the highest value, like `{'a': {'1': 4, '2': 4}}`? Pick one arbitrarily?

Answer (score 10):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with `max`:

```
d={'a':{'1':4,'2':6},'b':{'1':5,'2':10}}
new_d = {a:max(b, key=b.get) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': '2', 'b': '2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'a': {'1':4,'2':6},'b': {'1':5,'2':10}}

newd = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    max_value = max([i for i in value.values()])
    for k in value:
            if value[k] == max_value:
                    newd[key] = k

print(newd)
# prints '{'a': '2', 'b': '2'}'
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants the key corresponding to the highest value, not the key that's highest in itself.

Comment: Mmm ok I misunderstood, I'll edit my answer

Comment: now it should be fine. tho idk what the op wants when there's more than one key corresponding to the highest value.

Comment: That's a good question.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    new_dict[k] = max(v.values())
```